# Acceder al contenido del archivo pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy queriendo acceder al contenido del archivo de dependencias de un proyecto de Flutter, concretamente al archivo "pubspec.yaml", un archivo que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto.

Para conseguirlo, he tratado de seguir alguno de los ejemplos que he llegado a encontrar, como alguno de los que se pueden ver en este **[enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app/)**.
Por ejemplo, empleando el paquete "**[yaml](https://pub.dev/packages/yaml)**":

```
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {      
    File f = new File("pubspec.yaml");
    f.readAsString().then((String text) {
      Map yaml = loadYaml(text);
      print(yaml['name']);
      print(yaml['description']);
      print(yaml['version']);
      print(yaml['author']);
      print(yaml['homepage']);
      print(yaml['dependencies']);
    });
}
```

Todos me dan el mismo error o excepción de que no encuentra el archivo, sea cuál sea la ruta hacia el mencionado archivo (que no sé si se debe apuntar como si fuera desde el lugar dónde se ubica el ".lib/main.dart" o no):

> E/flutter (12128): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
>   E/flutter (12128): #0      _File.open.  (dart:io/file_impl.dart:366:9)
>   E/flutter (12128): #1      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
>   E/flutter (12128): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
>   E/flutter (12128): #3      _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
>   E/flutter (12128): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
>   E/flutter (12128): #5      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
>   E/flutter (12128): #6      Future._completeWithValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
>   E/flutter (12128): #7      Future._asyncComplete.  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
>   E/flutter (12128): #8      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
>   E/flutter (12128): #9      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
>   E/flutter (12128): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
>   E/flutter (12128): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
>   E/flutter (12128): #12     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
>   E/flutter (12128): #13     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)

Lo que no he llegado a hacer es incluir la referencia de este archivo "pubspec.yaml" dentro de él mismo en su apartado de ASSETS.

¿Alguna, por tanto, de cómo solucionar el problema que planteo?

Saludos.

Comment: No es posible hacerlo en tiempo de ejecución , podrías usar un generador de código, para que lea el pubspec.yml, genere las clases y valores correspondientes y eso puedas leerlo dentro de tu app (en runtime)

Comment: Otra cosa que podrías hacer es duplicar el archivo y meterlo en tu carpeta assets, para que pueda ser leído como cualquier archivo en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Bueno, pues si, se trataba de sacar un dato de una de las dimensiones del contenido del archivo "pubspec.yaml" para hacer una determinada tarea dentro de la aplicación. Y lo he conseguido, referenciando el propio archivo "pubspec.yaml" como un "asset" del proyecto. No me había atrevido pues creía que me iba a dar error de hacer referencia a un archivo dentro del mismo, pero va bien. A continuación, incluyo la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tras ciertas pruebas realizadas, he logrado obtener el contenido del archivo "pubspec.yaml" e imprimir, tanto, por la terminal, como en la pantalla del dispositivo, todo o parte de ese contenido.

De primeras, aunque me parecía ilógico hacerlo, es necesario registrar el propio archivo que se quiere manipular dentro del apartado de `assets` "pubspec.yaml":

```
  assets:
    - assets/user.json
    - assets/user.yaml
    - pubspec.yaml
```

Luego, he modificado la captura del contenido del archivo ya que, aún, tras registrar el archivo como ASSET, sigue saliendo la EXCEPCIÓN de que no se encuentra o no puede abrir el archivo.

```
E/flutter (14718): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Así que, ahora, aparte de seguir empleando el paquete de "yaml" que indiqué en el momento que sea necesario, el código para la obtención del contenido del archivo pasa a ser un método que devuelve un `Future` de forma asíncrona, por lo que el MAIN debe ser, igualmente, asíncrono para recibir ese valor.

De primeras, he realizado diversas pruebas, tanto con el "pubspec.yaml", como con otros dos archivos ("assets/user.json" y "assets/user.yaml"), para saber el mejor método de conseguir lo que se deseaba, por lo que he llegado a implementar, dos nuevos métodos.

El contenido de estos dos otros archivos es éste:

[assets/user.json]

```
{
  "name": "Pete Houston",
  "job": "Software Engineer",
  "homepage": "https://fluttermaster.com",
  "year": 2019
}
```

[assets/user.yaml]

```
name: Pete Houston

job: Software Engineer

homepage: https://fluttermaster.com

year: 2019
```

De los dos nuevos métodos que he llegado a implementar en un primer término, uno devuelve la respuesta en formato de `String` y otro en formato de `Map`:

```
/// Asumiendo que la ruta recibida es para acceder a un archivo registrado como ASSET.
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}

/// Asumiendo que la ruta recibida es para acceder a un archivo registrado como ASSET.
Future<Map> getFileDataMap(String path) async {
  final String resp = await rootBundle.loadString(path);

  return loadYaml(resp);
}
```

Con ambos métodos, se obtiene el resultado del contenido de archivo que se especifica, si bien, en el caso de llamar al `getFileData()`, para el "pubspec.yaml", solamente, se llega a obtener parte del contenido.
Empleando el `getFileDataMap` si que se llega a obtener el contenido completo del "pubspec.yaml".

Imprimiendo, dentro del MAIN, la respuesta del método, se llega a obtener el `Map` completo del contenido del "pubspec.yaml", y/o alguna dimensión concreta del contenido, y/o el tipo de esa dimensión, por ejemplo:

```
String pubspecYaml     = 'pubspec.yaml';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  fileName = pubspecYaml;
  Map dataMap = await getFileDataMap(fileName);

  print('-> dataMap (en su TOTALIDAD): $dataMap');
  print('');
  print('-> dataMap[flutter][assets]: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets']}');
  print('-> tipo: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'].runtimeType}');
  print('');
  print('-> dataMap[flutter][assets][0]: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'][0]}');
  print('-> tipo: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'][0].runtimeType}');

  //...
}
```

Imprimiéndose esto en el espacio de la terminal:

```
I/flutter (15368): -> dataMap (en su TOTALIDAD): {name: flutt_files_access, description: A new Flutter project., version: 1.0.0+1, author: Zacktagnan's Productions, year: 2020, environment: {sdk: >=2.1.0 <3.0.0}, dependencies: {flutter: {sdk: flutter}, yaml: ^2.2.0, cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2}, dev_dependencies: {flutter_test: {sdk: flutter}}, flutter: {uses-material-design: true, assets: [assets/user.json, assets/user.yaml, pubspec.yaml]}}
I/flutter (15368):
I/flutter (15368): -> dataMap[flutter][assets]: [assets/user.json, assets/user.yaml, pubspec.yaml]
I/flutter (15368): -> tipo: YamlList
I/flutter (15368):
I/flutter (15368): -> dataMap[flutter][assets][0]: assets/user.json
I/flutter (15368): -> tipo: String
```

Con ello todo, ya habría una forma de obtener todo o cosas concretas del archivo de "pubspec.yaml" (o de cualquier otro archivo, en principio).

A partir de aquí, a modo adicional, he seguido haciendo pruebas, implementando otras formas de conseguir ciertas partes del contenido del archivo "pubspec.yaml", como el método `getValueFromFileDataMap` que recibe la posible dimensión del elemento a consultar dentro del `Map` disponible del contenido del archivo.

También, he pasado ciertos valores del archivo al típico `MyApp` para plasmarlos dentro de la pantalla del `HomePage` (teniendo que pasar, pues, los valores recibidos por `MyApp` hacia el `HomePage`).

Y, por otro lado, dentro del `HomePage`, por medio de un `FutureBuilder`, he llegado a obtener, de nuevo. otra copia, en formato `Map`, del mismo contenido del "pubspec.yaml".
Todo para plasmar otra forma de obtener el mencionado contenido.

Aquí, un pantallazo de la pantalla de `HomePage` de la aplicación dónde se muestra ciertos datos sacados del "pubsepc.yaml":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para todo aquel que no esté muy familiarizado con el funcionamiento del `FutureBuilder`, en este **[enlace](https://blog.gcoding.academy/future-builder-un-pequeno-ejemplo/)**, se explica bastante bien.

Lo único a reseñar en cuanto a EXCEPCIONES, aunque no llegan a afectar al funcionamiento de la aplicación, se siguen presentando estas que pongo a continuación:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>#4a966):
The getter 'keys' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: keys

The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> 
lib\main.dart:378
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      HomePage.getStringForText  (package:flutt_files_access/main.dart:425:10)
#2      HomePage._getText.<anonymous closure>  (package:flutt_files_access/main.dart:406:21)
#3      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
#4      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4334
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  * 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99589 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Row 
lib\main.dart:331
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  * 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99595 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib\main.dart:282
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  */
```

La primera excepción se refiere al `keys` empleado en este método:

```
  String getStringForText(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data, String txtMsg) {
    data.keys.forEach((var k) {
      if ( k == data.keys.first ) {
        txtMsg += k;
      } else {
        txtMsg += ', $k';
      }
    });

    return txtMsg;
  }
```

Y las otras dos, parece ser, se refieren a cuestiones de "overflow".
Como he dicho, a simple vista, ninguna afecta al funcionamiento de la aplicación. Si bien, estaría bien saber que haría falta para evitarlas.
**¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo solucionarlas?**

Dejo, pues, todo el contenido, con ciertos comentarios explicativos para todo al que le pueda ayudar.

Contenido completo de los dos archivos que entran en juego:

[main.dart]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

import 'package:flutt_files_access/src/providers/file_provider.dart';


String getValueFromFileDataMap(Map dataMap, String keySetString) {
  String response;

  List<String> keysList = keySetString.split('|');

  bool isKeyString;
  List<dynamic> dataMapKeys = [];

  for(String key in keysList) {
    isKeyString = int.tryParse(key) == null;
    //var item = isKeyString ? key : int.parse(key);
    dataMapKeys.add( isKeyString ? key : int.parse(key) );
    //dataMapKeys.add(key);
  }
  // print(dataMapKeys);

  // dataMapKeys.forEach( (var dataMapKey) {
  //   //Viendo el tipo de dato de cada elemento
  //   print( '[$dataMapKey] : ${dataMapKey.runtimeType}' );
  // });

  switch ( dataMapKeys.length ) {
    case 1:
      response = dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ].toString();
      break;
    case 2:
      response = dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ].toString();
      break;
    case 3:
      response = dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ][ dataMapKeys[2] ].toString();
      break;
    case 4:
      response = dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ][ dataMapKeys[2] ][ dataMapKeys[3] ].toString();
      break;
  }

  return response;
}

/// Asumiendo que la ruta recibida es para acceder a un archivo registrado como ASSET.
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}

/// Asumiendo que la ruta recibida es para acceder a un archivo registrado como ASSET.
Future<Map> getFileDataMap(String path) async {
  final String resp = await rootBundle.loadString(path);

  return loadYaml(resp);
}

String fileName;
String assetsUserJson = 'assets/user.json';
String assetsUserYaml = 'assets/user.yaml';
String pubspecYaml     = 'pubspec.yaml';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  fileName = assetsUserJson;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  fileName = assetsUserYaml;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //- Mientras, todavía, no se ha registrado el "pubspec.yaml" como ASSET:
  //    -> Se produce una excepción como:
  //          FlutterError (Unable to load asset: pubspec.yaml)
  fileName = pubspecYaml;
  //::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  //- Pero, tras registrarlo como archivo ASSET, dentro de su propio contenido,
  //ya funciona, aunque, solamente, una parte se llega a imprimir (puede que,
  //solamente, se corte en la Terminal y no si se imprimiera en pantalla)
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  String data = await getFileData(fileName);


  //Con la forma efectuada a partir de ahora SI que se obtiene la totalidad del
  //contenido del archivo "pubspec.yaml".
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Map dataMap = await getFileDataMap(fileName);

  print('-> data (en formato String, pero parcial):');
  print(data);
  print('');
  print('-> dataMap (en su TOTALIDAD): $dataMap');
  print('');
  print('-> dataMap[flutter][assets]: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets']}');
  print('-> tipo: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'].runtimeType}');
  print('');
  print('-> dataMap[flutter][assets][0]: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'][0]}');
  print('-> tipo: ${dataMap['flutter']['assets'][0].runtimeType}');

  String clave;
  bool esString;
  clave = '0';
  clave = 'flutter';
  esString = int.tryParse(clave) == null;
  print(esString);
  clave = 'flutter';
  List<List<String>> claveValor = [];
  claveValor.add([clave]);

  print(claveValor[0]);
  print(claveValor[0].runtimeType);
  print(dataMap[claveValor[0][0]]);
  print(dataMap['flutter']);

  //=======================================================================

  /**
   * Se recibe algo a modo de un conjunto de claves como: xxx|xxx|xxx:
   * 
   * - según las partes de separadas del conjunto recibido,
   * se llamará una determinada dimensión del dataMap
   * 
   * - deberá verificarse si la parte de clave, inicialmente String,
   * debe convertirse a int o dejarse como String.
   * 
   * - finalmente, por ejemplo, teniendo 3 partes de clave, el valor demandado, se obtendrá así:
   *    dataMap[parte1][parte2][parte3]
   */
  String keySetString;
  //keySetString = 'name';
  //keySetString = 'environment|sdk';
  //keySetString = 'dependencies|flutter|sdk';
  //keySetString = 'dependencies|cupertino_icons';
  //keySetString = 'dev_dependencies|flutter_test';
  //keySetString = 'flutter|uses-material-design';
  keySetString = 'flutter|assets|0';

  //--------------------------------------------------------

  List<String> keysList = keySetString.split('|');

  bool isKeyString;
  List<dynamic> dataMapKeys = [];

  for(String key in keysList) {
    isKeyString = int.tryParse(key) == null;
    //var item = isKeyString ? key : int.parse(key);
    dataMapKeys.add( isKeyString ? key : int.parse(key) );
    //dataMapKeys.add(key);
  }
  print(dataMapKeys);

  dataMapKeys.forEach( (var dataMapKey) {
    print( '[$dataMapKey] : ${dataMapKey.runtimeType}' );
  });

  switch ( dataMapKeys.length ) {
    case 1:
      print( dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ] );
      break;
    case 2:
      print( dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ] );
      break;
    case 3:
      print( dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ][ dataMapKeys[2] ] );
      break;
    case 4:
      print( dataMap[ dataMapKeys[0] ][ dataMapKeys[1] ][ dataMapKeys[2] ][ dataMapKeys[3] ] );
      break;
  }

  String value = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, keySetString);

  print('');
  print('Desde el método [getValueFromFileDataMap]');
  print('----------------------------------------------');
  print('-> dataMap[$keySetString]: $value');

  Map<String, String> appDataMap = {};
  appDataMap['name']         = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, 'name');
  appDataMap['description']  = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, 'description');
  appDataMap['version']      = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, 'version');
  appDataMap['author']       = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, 'author');
  appDataMap['year']         = getValueFromFileDataMap(dataMap, 'year');

  runApp(MyApp(
    appDataMap: appDataMap,
  ));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map<String, String> appDataMap;

  MyApp({ @required this.appDataMap });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),

      home: HomePage(
        appDataMap: appDataMap,
      ),

    );

  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map<String, String> appDataMap;

  HomePage({
    Key key,
    @required this.appDataMap
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextStyle contentTitleStyle = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 20,
  );
  final TextStyle contentTextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          appDataMap['name'].toUpperCase(),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'v.${appDataMap['version']}',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox( width: 15, ),
        ],
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Descripción:',
                  style: contentTitleStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  ' ${appDataMap['description']}',
                  style: contentTextStyle,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 30.0,
              indent: 15.0,
              endIndent: 15.0,
              thickness: 2.2,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Dependencias Principales:',
                      style: contentTitleStyle,
                    ),
                    _getText( pubspecYaml, 'dependencies' ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 30.0,
              indent: 15.0,
              endIndent: 15.0,
              thickness: 2.2,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Dependencias de Desarrollo:',
                      style: contentTitleStyle,
                    ),
                    _getText( pubspecYaml, 'dev_dependencies' ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox( width: 35, ),
          Text(
            appDataMap['author'],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Copyright ${appDataMap['year']}',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox( width: 5, ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

  ////Widget _getText() {
  Widget _getText(String pathFile, String keySetString) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      ////future: fileProvider.cargarDataJsonToString( assetsUserJson ),
      ////future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToString( assetsUserYaml ),
      ////future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap( pubspecYaml ),
      future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap( pathFile ),
      initialData: {},//opcional pero RECOMENDABLE, según el tipo de dato devuelto por el FUTURE
      ////builder: ( context, snapShot ) {
      builder: ( context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snapShot ) {

        String txtMsg = '';

        if (snapShot.hasData) {
          ////Map data = snapShot.data['dependencies'];
          ////Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snapShot.data[keySetString];

          //print('-> data.entries.first: ${data.entries.first}');
          //print('-> data.entries.first.key: ${data.entries.first.key}');
          //print('-> data.keys.first: ${data.entries.first.key}');

          //List<dynamic> listData = data.keys.toList();

          // data.keys.forEach((var k) {
          //   if ( k == data.keys.first ) {
          //     txtMsg += k;
          //   } else {
          //     txtMsg += ', $k';
          //   }
          // });
          txtMsg += getStringForText(snapShot.data[keySetString], txtMsg);

        } else if (snapShot.hasError) {
          txtMsg = '${snapShot.error}';
        } else {
          txtMsg = 'Esperando el resultado...';
        }

        return Text(
          txtMsg,
          style: contentTextStyle,
        );

      },
    );
  }

  String getStringForText(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data, String txtMsg) {
    data.keys.forEach((var k) {
      if ( k == data.keys.first ) {
        txtMsg += k;
      } else {
        txtMsg += ', $k';
      }
    });

    return txtMsg;
  }
}
```

[file_provider.dart]

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';


class _FileProvider {

  String data = '';

  _FileProvider();

  Future<String> cargarDataJsonToString(String fileUrl) async {
    final resp = await rootBundle.loadString(fileUrl);

    Map dataMap = json.decode( resp );
    ////print( dataMap );

    data = dataMap['name'];
    //return data;

    return dataMap.toString();
  }

  Future<String> cargarDataYamlToString(String fileUrl) async {
    final resp = await rootBundle.loadString(fileUrl);

    Map dataMap = loadYaml( resp );
    ////print( dataMap );

    data = dataMap['name'];
    //return data;

    return dataMap.toString();
  }

  Future<Map> cargarDataYamlToMap(String fileUrl) async {
    final resp = await rootBundle.loadString(fileUrl);

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> dataMap = loadYaml( resp );

    return dataMap;
    //return data;

  }

}

final fileProvider = _FileProvider();
```

Eso es todo. Aquí queda esto para todo el que le pueda ayudar. Se presta, igualmente, a toda valoración de cualquier experto que pueda aportar cualquier mejora u opinión.

Comment: @diegoveloper ... a ver que te parece ... Saludos

Comment: ahí mencionas que te sale el error : Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.yaml' ,  al final si pudiste leerlo?  lo tuviste q mover? funciona en modo release?

Comment: No, no he movido de sitio el archivo; si lo moviese de lugar, supongo, que la cuestión de las dependencias del proyecto fallaría, ¿no? ... Lo que comentaba es que, con el código que expongo en la pregunta, aún, tras registrar el archivo como "asset" dentro de él mismo, me seguía fallando con ese código, puede que por no ser una tarea "async" la carga del archivo, o igual por otra cosa, no sé. Por eso, basándome en otro ejercicio práctico que tenía, implementé esta forma de carga que he puesto ... Sobre lo último que comentas del "release", la verdad que no sé exactamente a qué te refieres.

Comment: Lo he probado, únicamente, sobre un emulador, osea, en desarrollo. No he llegado, aún, a probarlo en uno real o producción, si eso es a lo que te refieres con "release".

Comment: Sobre lo de las excepciones que comento casi final de la respuesta, antes del contenido completo, ¿sabrías algo?

Comment: Lo mejor sería que crees otra pregunta con el error que te aparece