# The getter keys was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Dentro de una aplicación implementada en Flutter llega el momento que recupero el contenido de un determinado archivo. El `Map` de respuesta es recibido por un `FutureBuilder` que examina el `data` recibido para recorrerlo y plasmar la información deseada dentro de un widget de `Text()`.

Todo funciona bien, en principio. Pero, si que, aún y todo, llegan a salir una serie de excepciones que me gustaría resolver a pesar de que, lo que parece, no afectan, de primeras, al funcionamiento.

En concreto, el bloque de excepciones que me salen en la terminal es éste:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(dirty, 
state: _FutureBuilderState<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>#4a966):
The getter 'keys' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: keys

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> 
lib\main.dart:378
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      HomePage.getStringForText  (package:flutt_files_access/main.dart:425:10)
#2      HomePage._getText.<anonymous closure>  (package:flutt_files_access/main.dart:406:21)
#3      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
#4      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4334
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  * 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99589 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Row 
lib\main.dart:331
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  * 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99595 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib\main.dart:282
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  */
```

Y, supuestamente, el bloque de código dónde se produce, al menos, la primera excepción, es éste:

```
  String getStringForText(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data, String txtMsg) {
    data.keys.forEach((var k) {
      if ( k == data.keys.first ) {
        txtMsg += k;
      } else {
        txtMsg += ', $k';
      }
    });

    return txtMsg;
  }
```

Este método es llamado desde dentro de un `FutureBuilder` de este otro método:

```
  Widget _getText(String pathFile, String keySetString) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap( pathFile ),
      initialData: {},//opcional pero RECOMENDABLE, según el tipo de dato devuelto por el FUTURE
      builder: ( context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snapShot ) {

        String txtMsg = '';

        if (snapShot.hasData) {
          txtMsg += getStringForText(snapShot.data[keySetString], txtMsg);

        } else if (snapShot.hasError) {
          txtMsg = '${snapShot.error}';
        } else {
          txtMsg = 'Esperando el resultado...';
        }

        return Text(
          txtMsg,
          style: contentTextStyle,
        );

      },
    );
  }
```

A su vez, este método de `_getText` es llamado desde dentro de un `Row` del `Scaffold` para plasmar el `Text()` final.

El código completo está disponible en la respuesta de este otro **[post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337527/acceder-al-contenido-del-archivo-pubspec-yaml/337803)**.

Saludos.

Comment: hmm el error es claro, dice que  `data` es null, al momento de llamar a `data.keys` se produce el error ,prueba validando   if (data != null)  { ... }  else { return ""; }

Comment: Para comprobar si en verdad el DATA llegaba NULL o no al método, he puesto un `print(data)` antes del `data.keys.forEach(){...}` y, al hacer un Hot Restart, por la terminal, he visto que, nada más llegar al método el valor de DATA si que es NULL, entonces, pasa por `data.keys` y, al ser NULL, se produce la excepción. Pero, al segundo después, ya llega de nuevo DATA con el contenido necesario y, entonces, se llega a hacer, finalmente, el `forEach`, por eso, supongo que los datos se plasman por pantalla y el error de excepción, solamente, se llega a apreciar por la terminal.

Comment: Con la sugerencia del `if(data != null) {...}` ya no salen las comentadas excepciones. ¿El problema está relacionado con cuestiones de ASYN y AWAIT?

Comment: Asi es, por eso es necesario que agregues mas datos , como el widget donde usas FutureBuilder

Comment: ¿Hablas de poner el widget dónde uso el FutureBuilder en la pregunta? Si es eso, no lo había puesto poque había puesto un enlace al lugar dónde ya estaba disponible. Pero, bueno, edito la pregunta y ya está. Y, sino, entonces,  ¿el problema era por cuestiones de ASYN y AWAIT? ¿aparte de con el `if(data != null)` habría otra forma de evitar el problema o prevenirlo?

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con el codigo del futurebuilder, ahi esta el problema

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuál sería, pues, la forma correcta de tratar el problema aparte de con el condicional o esa es la mejor, y única, manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando un Map vacío en `initialData`.

```
FutureBuilder(
     future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap( pathFile ),
     initialData: {},
```

Al hacer eso, haces que la validación `if (snapShot.hasData)` pase correctamente ya que el valor inicial es `{}`, es decir tiene data.

Por lo que al llamar a `snapShot.data[keySetString]` , retorna un nulo que es el que genera el error en tu método `getStringForText`.

Mi recomendación es que quites el atributo `initialData: {},` , para que haga la validación correcta.

Comment: ¿Osea, que si incluyo la propiedad de `initialData: {}` como propiedad de FutureBuilder, no tendría que añadir el `if(snapShot.hasData)` y viceversa?

Comment: no necesariamente, eso quiere decir que al inicio tendrá data, {} ,  pero luego quizas tu método `fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap( pathFile )` podría retornar nulo ,entonces ya no entraría ahí.

Comment: Entonces, según tu experiencia, ¿es mejor obviar el `initialData` e incluir el `if(snapShot.hasData)` siempre para los casos en los que se reciba un `null` desde el `fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap(pathFile)`? ¿Y con esto dejo de tener que incluir el `if(data != null)` que sugerías al principio o, aún así, tengo que inlcuirlo igualmente?

Comment: Si, en este caso no necesitas el initialData,  tu validación if(snapshot.hasData) está bien ,   con eso ya quita la validación  if(data!=null) . Si la respuesta te sirvió, márcala como solucionada.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias.

Comment: ¿Alguna buena referencia sobre el tema de ASYNC/AWAIT? No llego, del todo, a cogerle el tranquillo a esta cuestión.

Comment: sí, mira este video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, saludos.